# LAN multiplayer game for desktop and Android in Unity 3D

Tags: unity, multiplayer

How can I add an option "Multiplayer on LAN" to my desktop and Android game? I am using Unity 3D, and I am currently building a chess game.

Just give me the source or a specific path that I have to follow. Any shared material or criticism will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is just from my experience in creating something using LAN.

When you create your UI, under your connection buttons etc (You probably have this by now) for connecting via lan, have the IP created start with something like 192.168... This will absolutely not work over the internet, but will allow your unity game to connect VIA the lan network, you will of course need all your code for creating a local client and a server etc on the local client, but i assume you have that already (If not i can update my answer to give advice on that)

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/help-setting-up-a-lan-connection.117092/ : This question is good help for a direction to go in, and that forum has allot of resources if you do some digging.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you have working online that's either p2p or has server running on the host's machine (minecraft, terraria, etc..) you already have working LAN, the only difference is the IP would be a local IP instead of a public IP.

if you have no online whatsoever you should probably be looking for that instead of just LAN, since it's the same thing, playing over network, size of the network is irrelevant.

Comment: okay @Brian guide me about it a little bit.